# Sign confusion in a BFS lemma

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

I have a confusion related the Lemma 22.1 in Cormen Leiserson Rivest Stein's Introduction to Algorithm book,

Here it is written that delta(s,v) <= delta(s,u) +1 ,where s,u,v are the vertices of a graph G
My question is why <= is used ? Won't that be = only ? I am learning Algorithms and Data Structures.
[image: Image from CLSR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the graph $G = (V,E)$ with $V = \{s,u,v\}$ and $E =\{ (s,u), (s,v), (u,v) \}$. You have:
$$
\delta(s,v) = 1 <  1+1 = \delta(s,u) + 1.
$$

Comment: Wow thanks a lot brother, got my answer